# Ubuntu Eclipse CDT unresolved include <stdio.h>

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu, include, eclipse-cdt

Ubuntu 10.10 Ecelipse-cpp-helios-SR2-linux with eclipse-cdt

C and C++ project are fine

when i create a makefile project use #include  for C or  for C++

all gave unresolved inclusion: error, so that i can't build project

Please Help

I'm having trouble running C in eclipse. It first gives me weird syntax errors or tells me that

## include  is an "Unresolved inclusion"

It also will not let me build, saying "(Cannot run program "make": Launching failed)"

Am I missing something? please help.

Thanks

Comment: Please rephrase the question.

Comment: Do you have make installed? Have you created a Makefile for you project?

Answer (score 0):

There is no compiler coming with Eclipse CDT out of the box. You need to have it externally installed on your system.

You should consider to install gcc & make on your Ubuntu system to be able to build your application within Eclipse.